# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Broken Install

Tags: boot, uefi, system-installation, 14.04

So I downloaded the latest amd64 iso, burnt to disk and booted from it. 
When I first boot to disk the console shows an error that quickly disappears along the lines of "Could not find \EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi".

It disappears and continues to boot to the ubuntu splash screen, at which point the screen turns black and my computer restarts. I have tried numerous different methods that all result in the same thing.

I previously had ubuntu 13.10 installed so I tried using the upgrade option which seemed to install fine, when booting it gets to the login prompt and then black screens and reboots like the installer does.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: You've clearly encountered a bug. Even if you find a workaround, I strongly recommend that you [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Have you tried to re download the iso?

Answer (score 1):

What program did you use to burn the image?  I know most programs do not create an EFI bootable disk.

You can either use one that does (what OS are you on now?)

Or disable EFI and boot from Legacy BIOS (note that if you do this, you cannot switch back without re-installing or staying in legacy)

Comment: I did try booting in legacy mode, I'll try creating a efi bootable disk.

Comment: It is also a good idea to verify the checksum of the download if you're downloading from a mirror.  

I prefer to use torrents to download ISO's like this because they will verify the sum once it is downloaded and replace anything that was corrupted during the download process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a USB install.

The easiest way is to use Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.4.8. To create the USB installer, download the .iso file again and check its checksum.

Then, disable EFI and run the install from USB.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to be a problem with either some MSI motherboards or the AMD A8 5600K. A workaround is to add `acpi=off` to the grub config which seems to solve the problem for me.